# Can I build a dynamic library within a docker container which can be linked to from outside docker?

Tags: docker, dll

I have a library that I provide others with by shipping a dll. I've heard about docker and thought that it might be a good thing to use since my library is using other libraries and by providing a docker image I don't have to force the consumer of my library to install for example python for my library to work (there are other reasons as well for why docker is a good choice). The point is that my dll is using "environment resources" that I want to have control over, hence docker.

My novice understanding of docker is that people are using it for running apps or processes. I'm having a hard time finding out information about only containing a shared dynamic library (dll, in my case).

So my question is: Is it possible to create a docker container containing a dll so that end user (who lives outside the docker container) can link to the dll (within the container)?

Answer (score 0):

No. The whole point of the docker container is isolation. Linking into an isolated environment "unisolates" it. Linking from outside into the container would require the guest to have access to the hosts' virtual memory address spaces. And this would negate all security and stability aspects of the isolation.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not the way Docker works. Your users wont be able to link they executables against your container.

What you may want to do is to review the concept and provide **service** instead of library, using REST api, for example. In this case Docker container would become ideal solution for you. But I have no idea if your library' function could be transformed into tcp services.